# How do you use for loops with arrays properly?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I am trying to create a program that creates good and bad collectibles and the characters have to find them.

Initialize:

```
{
    int width = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width;

    int height = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height;
    int xcoord = rnd.Next(width - 50);
    int ycoord = rnd.Next(height - 50);
    this.goodCollectibles = new Sprite[gC];
    this.badCollectibles = new Sprite[bC];
    for (int index = 0; index < gC; index++)
      goodCollectibles[index] = new Sprite(this, xcoord, ycoord, 50, 50, "gC");

    for (int index = 0; index < bC; index++)
      badCollectibles[index] = new Sprite(this, xcoord, ycoord, 50, 50, "bC");

    char1 = new ControllableSprite(this, xcoord, ycoord, 100, 100, "char1");
    char2 = new ControllableSprite(this, xcoord, ycoord, 100, 100, "char2");
}
```

Draw *if you win the game (by collecting more good collectibles/ less bad collectibles you become blue, if tie yellow, if you lose then red)*:

```
{
   spriteBatch.Begin();

   for (int index = 0; index < gC; index++)
      goodCollectibles[index].Draw(spriteBatch);
   for (int index = 0; index < bC; index++)
      badCollectibles[index].Draw(spriteBatch);

   if (char1.score > char2.score && counter > 1800)
   {
      char1.scoreColor = Color.Blue;
      char2.scoreColor = Color.Red;
   }
   else if (char2.score > char1.score && counter > 1800)
   {
      char2.scoreColor = Color.Blue;
      char1.scoreColor = Color.Red;
   }
   else if (char1.score == char2.score && counter > 1800)
   {
      char1.scoreColor = Color.Yellow;
      char2.scoreColor = Color.Yellow;
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific.  What are you expecting to see, what do you actually see?

Comment: You should also probably put the logic in the update.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your for-loop and array connection.

Your code:

```
for (int index = 0; index < gC; index++)
      goodCollectibles[index] = new Sprite(this, xcoord, ycoord, 50, 50, "gC");
```

looks already sufficient enough to let for-loops work correct with arrays.

However, I think the problem lies on your `rnd.Next`, because you've already used it before the for-loop, and thus it won't make new random throws.

Instead, put your `rnd.Next` statements inside the for-loop. Something like this:

```
for (int index = 0; index < gC; index++)
{
      goodCollectibles[index] = new Sprite(this, rnd.Next(width - 50), rnd.Next(height - 50), 50, 50, "gC");
}
```

That way it should work.